# Adding "s" to the verbs it doesn't belong to

Tags: verbs, usage, slang

Just curious about this thing, some people add -s in sentences like here: "I keeps my promises"
and I've also seen people both adding it and using it the normal way in the same paragraph of text. So what's this all about? Does it emphasize or indicate something other than the fact that whoever used it has made a mistake? Why would someone consciously make a mistake (considering other sentences in the paragraph don't have this -s). Hopefully someone can answer it.

Some examples:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_the_Bar
[image: Example]
https://genius.com/Company-flow-the-fire-in-which-you-burn-lyrics
etc

Comment: Possibly to make it sound deliberately childish/funny.  Children often get their grammar wrong when they are first learning to speak. JRR Tolkein did something similar with the speech of Gollum in the Lord of the Rings . . for example: "We wants it, we needs it. Must have the precious. They stole it from us. Sneaky little hobbitses. Wicked, tricksy, false!"

Comment: There are many reasons why someone might do so: dialect, for humorous effect, due to an error, etc. You should therefore provide an actual example; otherwise, you're just inviting speculation.

Comment: This is common in some US and UK regional dialects. In Bristol, many local dialect speakers add an 's' to all forms of verbs, e.g. I keeps, you keeps, they keeps, ('us keeps' sometimes in some rural speech).

Comment: As for examples, a Google search provides plenty, here's one:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_the_Bar
and another one:
![Example](http://rezwaki.hldns.ru/Untitled_16.png)

Comment: Please put the examples in the actual text of your question, not links in the comments.

Comment: "Inside the Bar" is imitating working class or dialect speech.